D10 Webform not sending emails - Email sending skipped: Send aborted by hook_mail()
I would like to send webform notification upon saving a webform, but getting "Email sending skipped: Send aborted by hook_mail().." I tried search, but no luck anywhere..
Drupal 10.2, symfony mailer test working via trasnport SMPT and Sendmail as well. Plus system emails are working fine
Stucked here.. :/ Any help would be great! Thank You!

We can't answer without more information from you. This is the symfony_mailer module throwing an exception because an implementation of hook_mail on the Drupal site returned an empty or missing 'send' key on the $message array. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/symfony_mailer/-/blob/1.x/src/Plugin/EmailBuilder/LegacyEmailBuilder.php#L131 You have to hunt down every hook_mail implementation on the site to figure out which one is the problem.
